# Jsoup fork: maven failed to collect dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsoup, pom.xml, m2e

I forked jsoup and I executed maven install via eclipse's m2e plugin. 
The error I get is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.1.0:manifest (bundle-manifest) on project jsoup: Execution bundle-manifest of goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.1.0:manifest failed: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.1.0 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.7: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:pom:2.0.7 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.7/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.7.pom
-> [Help 1]
```

I'm a complete noob with maven. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just suffer a connection timeout... Retry later or use a maven proxy.

The file exists:  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.7/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.7.pom